# Creating a list using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the IRS past forms site to gather the data for studying data mining. This web data contains a big table with 101 pages.

Here's the link:
https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html

[picture of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKADO.png)

My task:

**Taking a list of tax form names (ex: "Form W-2", "Form 1095-C"), search the website
and return some informational results. Specifically, you must return the "Product
Number", the "Title", and the maximum and minimum years the form is available for
download. The forms returned should be an exact match for the input (ex: "Form W-2"
should not return "Form W-2 P", etc.) The results should be returned as json.**

MY CODE SO FAR:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html"


html_content = requests.get(url).text


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())

forms_table = soup.find("table", class_= "picklist-dataTable")
forms_table_data = forms_table.find_all("tr")  # contains 2 rows


headings = []
for tr in forms_table_data[0].find_all("th"):
    
    headings.append(tr.b.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())

print(headings)
```

THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING HORRIBLY STUCK:

```
data = {}
for table, heading in zip(forms_table_data, headings):
    
    t_headers = []
    for th in table.find_all("th"):
       
        t_headers.append(th.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())
    
    table_data = []
    for tr in table.tbody.find_all("tr"): # find all tr's from table's tbody
        t_row = {}
        
for td, th in zip(tr.find_all("td"), t_headers): 
     t_row[th] = td.text.replace('\n', '').strip()
     table_data.append(t_row)

    
    data[heading] = table_data

print(data)
```

I also seem to be missing how to incorporate the rest of the pages on the site.

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: A link to the page or showing the HTML itself is [much better than a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) which tells me nothing about the markup we're working with. Ideally, show the exact output df you desire (as text) along with the input so answerers can show you how to get from point A to point B. There's also [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) so you can probably just load it right into pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way as mentioned to get table in data frame is `read_html()` - Be aware that pandas read all the table from the site and put them in a list of data frames. In your case you have to slice it by [3]

Cause your question is not that clear and hard to read with all that images, you should improve it.

**Example (Form W-2)**

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_html('pd.read_html('https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html?resultsPerPage=200&sortColumn=sortOrder&indexOfFirstRow=0&criteria=formNumber&value=Form+W-2&isDescending=false')[3]
```

Than you can filter and sort the data frame and export as json.

Comment: This is the task: Taking a list of tax form names (ex: "Form W-2", "Form 1095-C"), search the website
and return some informational results. Specifically, you must return the "Product
Number", the "Title", and the maximum and minimum years the form is available for
download. The forms returned should be an exact match for the input (ex: "Form W-2"
should not return "Form W-2 P", etc.) The results should be returned as json.